# Is there a way I can defer the .Where clause in a LINQ statement?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have this code here. I think it's not very efficient and I would like to know if there is a way that I make it so some of the .Where clauses are added at the start or the end rather than repeated three times. I would appreciate if anyone can give me any advice and show how I could do this:

```
      List<Phrase> phrases;

        switch (options.PhraseTypeSelectId)
        {
            case 0:
                phrases = await db.Phrases
                .Where(w => ((w.CategoryId == options.CategorySelectId || options.CategorySelectId == null) ||
                             (w.ChapterId == options.ChapterSelectId || options.ChapterSelectId == null)))
                .Where(w => (w.EnglishAscii >= es1 && w.EnglishAscii <= ee1) || (w.EnglishAscii >= es2 && w.EnglishAscii <= ee2))
                .Where(w => (w.RomajiAscii >= rs1 && w.RomajiAscii <= re1) || (w.RomajiAscii >= rs2 && w.RomajiAscii <= ee2))
                .Where(w => (options.CreatedBy == 0 || w.CreatedBy == options.CreatedBy))
                .Where(w => (options.ModifiedBy == 0 || w.ModifiedBy == options.ModifiedBy))
                .Where(w => (options.JLPT == 0 || w.JLPT == options.JLPT))
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToListAsync();
                return Ok(phrases);
            case 1:
                phrases = await db.Phrases
                .Where(w => ((w.CategoryId == options.CategorySelectId || options.CategorySelectId == null)))
                .Where(w => (w.EnglishAscii >= es1 && w.EnglishAscii <= ee1) || (w.EnglishAscii >= es2 && w.EnglishAscii <= ee2))
                .Where(w => (w.RomajiAscii >= rs1 && w.RomajiAscii <= re1) || (w.RomajiAscii >= rs2 && w.RomajiAscii <= ee2))
                .Where(w => (options.CreatedBy == 0 || w.CreatedBy == options.CreatedBy))
                .Where(w => (options.ModifiedBy == 0 || w.ModifiedBy == options.ModifiedBy))
                .Where(w => (options.JLPT == 0 || w.JLPT == options.JLPT))
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToListAsync();
                return Ok(phrases);
            case 2:
                phrases = await db.Phrases
                .Where(w => ((w.ChapterId == options.ChapterSelectId || options.ChapterSelectId == null)))
                .Where(w => (w.EnglishAscii >= es1 && w.EnglishAscii <= ee1) || (w.EnglishAscii >= es2 && w.EnglishAscii <= ee2))
                .Where(w => (w.RomajiAscii >= rs1 && w.RomajiAscii <= re1) || (w.RomajiAscii >= rs2 && w.RomajiAscii <= ee2))
                .Where(w => (options.CreatedBy == 0 || w.CreatedBy == options.CreatedBy))
                .Where(w => (options.ModifiedBy == 0 || w.ModifiedBy == options.ModifiedBy))
                .Where(w => (options.JLPT == 0 || w.JLPT == options.JLPT))
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToListAsync();
                return Ok(phrases);
        }
        return BadRequest();
```

I would like to include the switch statement as I tried without this and it became very confusing with the .Where clauses related to the PhraseTypeSelectId

Comment: I can´t see any differences between case 1 and 2.

Comment: Why not create a method containing the common logic for your cases, and add the case specific logic in the case itself?

Comment: You can make the assignment `phrases = await db.Phrases` outside the `select` clause. In `select cases` you can concatenate `where` expressions like `phrases = phrases.where()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I couldn't compile the example, I'm not 100% sure that this will compile either, but you should get the gist of it.

You can create specific expressions for the different `PhraseTypeSelecteId` and use it in the `.Where()` method later.

```
Expression<Func<Phrase, bool>> phraseTypePredicate = null;

switch (options.PhraseTypeSelectId)
{
    case 0:
        phraseTypePredicate =
            w => ((w.CategoryId == options.CategorySelectId || options.CategorySelectId == null) ||
                  (w.ChapterId == options.ChapterSelectId || options.ChapterSelectId == null));
        break;
    case 1:
        phraseTypePredicate =
            w => ((w.CategoryId == options.CategorySelectId || options.CategorySelectId == null));
        break;
    case 2:
        phraseTypePredicate =
            w => ((w.ChapterId == options.ChapterSelectId || options.ChapterSelectId == null));
        break;
}

if (phraseTypePredicate != null)
{
    List<Phrase> phrases = phrases = await db.Phrases
        .Where(phraseTypePredicate)
        .Where(w => (w.EnglishAscii >= es1 && w.EnglishAscii <= ee1) || (w.EnglishAscii >= es2 && w.EnglishAscii <= ee2))
        .Where(w => (w.RomajiAscii >= rs1 && w.RomajiAscii <= re1) || (w.RomajiAscii >= rs2 && w.RomajiAscii <= ee2))
        .Where(w => (options.CreatedBy == 0 || w.CreatedBy == options.CreatedBy))
        .Where(w => (options.ModifiedBy == 0 || w.ModifiedBy == options.ModifiedBy))
        .Where(w => (options.JLPT == 0 || w.JLPT == options.JLPT))
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToListAsync();
    return Ok(phrases);
}

return BadRequest();
```

Comment: Can you supply `Expression Tree` directly to the `Where` clause or does it needs to be compiled to a `Func<T,bool>`. You are not compiling the Expression tree.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj since this for an `IQueryable`, we want to keep it as an `Expression` to allow EntityFramework to perform the filter server-side.  If it's a `Func`, it would be using the `IEnumerable` version of the method and will cause the app to load all the rows and do the filtering client-side (aside: `AsNoTracking` and `ToListAsync` wouldn't work anyway if we were using the `IEnumerable` version of `Where`).

Comment: Alright thanks, looks like these calls `AsNoTracking()` and `ToListAsync()` gave you an idea regarding `IQueryable`, otherwise its not mentioned anywhere

Answer (score 3):

You could use the extension method `.AsQueryable()` this will return the former part of a linq statment as a queryable expression, allowing further manipulation and transformer if needed.

for example

```
var query =db.Phrases.where(phraseTypePredicate).AsQueryable();

switch(options.PhraseTypeSelectId)
{
   case 1: 
     query = query.where(case1Predicate);
     break;
   case 2: 
     query = query.where(case2Predicate);
     break;
   ... 
}

var results = query.ToList(); // or someother way of enumerating the expression
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the question is how to build a dynamic filter. To do that, you can start with basic `IQueryable<T>` and apply parameter based conditional `Where` like this:

```
var query = db.Phrases.AsQueryable();

bool categoryFilter = options.CategorySelectId != null && options.PhraseTypeSelectId != 2;
bool chapterFilter = options.ChapterSelectId != null && options.PhraseTypeSelectId != 1;
if (categoryFilter && chapterFilter) query = query
    .Where(w => w.CategoryId == options.CategorySelectId || w.ChapterId == options.ChapterSelectId);
else if (categoryFilter) query = query
    .Where(w => w.CategoryId == options.CategorySelectId);
else if (chapterFilter) query = query
   .Where(w => w.ChapterId == options.ChapterSelectId);

query = query
    .Where(w => (w.EnglishAscii >= es1 && w.EnglishAscii <= ee1) || (w.EnglishAscii >= es2 && w.EnglishAscii <= ee2))
    .Where(w => (w.RomajiAscii >= rs1 && w.RomajiAscii <= re1) || (w.RomajiAscii >= rs2 && w.RomajiAscii <= ee2));

if (options.CreatedBy != 0) query = query
    .Where(w => w.CreatedBy == options.CreatedBy);

if (options.ModifiedBy != 0)
    query = query.Where(w => w.ModifiedBy == options.ModifiedBy);

if (options.JLPT != 0)
    query = query.Where(w => w.JLPT == options.JLPT);

var phrases = await query
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();

return Ok(phrases);
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ queries on an `IQueryable` or an `IEnumerable` aren't evaluated until you actually iterate the results - by looping over it, or calling `ToList()` or suchlike.

Therefore, you can build things in stages, for example:

```
var exp = dbcontext.Logs.Where(x => x.Code == 4);
```

which won't execute any code on the database yet. Then you can later on say:

```
var logs = await exp.Where(x => x.Module == "AUTH").ToListAsync();
```

and that *will* execute the query, because of the `ToListAsync()`.

The massive advantage of this is being able to build up queries in stages with sensible methods (instead of slicing strings of SQL around), and trust that Entity Framework or whatever LINQ provider you're using will turn it into a reasonable query (which it does most of the time).

So for your enormous example, I'm not going to attempt to rewrite it here, but you can certainly do something in this form:

```
var query = await db.Phrases;
// common where clauses

switch (options.PhraseTypeSelectId) {
    case 0:
        query = query.Where(w => /* appropriate restriction for 0 */);
        break;
    // other cases
}

// more conditional where clauses perhaps

// projection clauses like Select()

// finally, execute the query
List<Phrases> phrases = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should also work (details may be wrong, just conceptional):

```
// common filters here:
var filtered = db.Phrases
       .Where(w => (w.EnglishAscii >= es1 && w.EnglishAscii <= ee1) || (w.EnglishAscii >= es2 && w.EnglishAscii <= ee2))
       .Where(w => (w.RomajiAscii >= rs1 && w.RomajiAscii <= re1) || (w.RomajiAscii >= rs2 && w.RomajiAscii <= ee2))
       .Where(w => (options.CreatedBy == 0 || w.CreatedBy == options.CreatedBy))
       .Where(w => (options.ModifiedBy == 0 || w.ModifiedBy == options.ModifiedBy))
       .Where(w => (options.JLPT == 0 || w.JLPT == options.JLPT));

    // specific filters
    switch (options.PhraseTypeSelectId)
    {
        case 0:
            filtered = filtered 
                .Where(w => ((w.CategoryId == options.CategorySelectId || options.CategorySelectId == null) ||
                         (w.ChapterId == options.ChapterSelectId || options.ChapterSelectId == null)))
             break;
        case 1:
            filtered = filtered 
                .Where(w => ((w.CategoryId == options.CategorySelectId || options.CategorySelectId == null)))
             break;
        case 2:
            // ???
             break;
        default: 
           return BadRequest();
    }
    var phrases = async filtered
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToListAsync();
    return Ok(phrases);
```